# Create an "@msn.com" email address

Tags: email, windows-live-messenger

I want to create an email account in MSN that be like `something@msn.com`.

Is there any way to do that?

I found only a way to create `@live` and `@hotmail.com` email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an `@msn.com` email address using this link to [Account Services on Passport.NET](https://accountservices.passport.net/reg.srf?ns=msn.com&sl=1&lc=1033)

Comment: Link is 404ing.